# Unknown error. Operation failed: VPC Access did not have permission to resolve the subnet or the provided subnet does not exist

Tags: networking, vpc

Original error message: Operation failed: VPC Access did not have permission to resolve the subnet or the provided subnet does not exist.

Steps Followed:

1. Created a new Project la-gcp-cloud-run-demo
2. Created a subnet in the network with CIDR range 10.8.0.0/28
3. Created  a VPC Connector using the subnet 10.8.0.0/28

Note : While creating the same Connector on la-gcp-cloud-run-demo, On other projects like la-gcp-corp an ls-gcp-test.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFDzp.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've just recently encountered the same issue as yours.
I am assuming that you are connecting the projects via **Shared VPC**.

You missed 2 steps from your original one:

```
Steps Followed:

1. Created a new Project la-gcp-cloud-run-demo
2. Created a subnet in the network with CIDR range 10.8.0.0/28
3. Created a VPC Connector using the subnet 10.8.0.0/28
```

**4. Navigate to your target project and enable [Serverless VPC API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/vpcaccess.googleapis.com?_ga=2.47901664.61453650.1648526192-1999308113.1573742607)** -- Once enabled, go to IAM Permissions and copy the freshly created gcp-sa-vpcaccess.iam.gserviceaccount
**5. Go to your Shared VPC Host project and add your new gcp-sa-vpcaccess.iam.gserviceaccount under IAM add set the role as networkUser**

Once you have the right permissions, you will be able to create Connectors without any problem.

Hoping this helps!

Comment: I somehow had to create (and delete) a dummy VPC Access Connector in the project before the `service-${project-number}@gcp-sa-vpcaccess.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account got created.

Comment: this was very helpful, it's basically a condensed (digestible) version of the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/shared-vpc-service-projects#grant-permissions

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me today i have to made an account with this format in the "host vpc" @cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com , you have to puto the account ID not the name, the account is in twelve digits. Give to this network user role.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).